# Dog that was exchanged for a lamb

Tags: korban, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, ki-teitzei, maseches-temura

> לֹֽא־תָבִיא֩ אֶתְנַ֨ן זוֹנָ֜ה וּמְחִ֣יר כֶּ֗לֶב בֵּ֛ית ה
>   אֱלֹ-הֶ֖-יךָ
>   ([Devarim 23:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.23.19?lang=bi&aliyot=0))

Why a dog that was exchanged for a lamb is not allowed to be brought as an offering? Why are dogs singled out here?

Answer (score 6):

It is a sheep who was traded against a dog that is forbidden to be brought as an offering. See the gemara in [Temura 30a](https://www.sefaria.org/Temurah.30a.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and following. Such a sheep is forbidden as the verse continues: as it is "abhorrent to the LORD your God.

Regarding dogs specifically artscroll, quoting Ramban, explains

> Dogs are considered abominations because they were often trained to be
>   vicious and this became a menace to the public. It is common for
>   sinners to try to legitimate the profits of their activities by
>   contributing to charitable causes. By forbidding the use as offerings
>   of animals given in exchange for harlotry or for dogs, the Torah
>   symbolizes that ill-gotten gains cannot be cleansed by using them for
>   holy ends; God regards such a practice as an abomination.

Beyond the general prohibition of exchanging animals for sacrifice (the topic of the tractate of Temura based on [Vayikra 27:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.27.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), there are other animals which are also prohibited as sacrifices, e.g., a cow that gores and kills a Jew and its offspring ([Temura 30b](https://www.sefaria.org/Temurah.30b.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).